# Number of Bijections such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, monotone-functions

Find the number of bijective functions $f:Z \to Z$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, $\forall x, y \in Z$

I substituted $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=0$

Now Keep $x=-y$, we get
$$f(0)=f(x)+f(-x)$$
$\implies$
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$
Now let $f(1)=m$ for some $m \in Z$

Then $f(-1)=-m$

So once the mapping of any integer is done, the mapping of its negative is simultaneously done.

But how to count number of bijections?

Comment: Well, if $f(1)=m$ then $f(2)=2m, f(3)=3m$ and so on.  So, for which $m$ is this a bijection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two: $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$. If $m=0$, then $f(1)=f(0)$ and then $f$ is not injective. And if $m>1$ or $m<-1$, then, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f(n)$ is a multiple of $m$, and therefore $f$ is not surjective.